# Mongoosejs middleware hooks "pre" find questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I am in need of help. I have a specific situation where I need to have my Mongoose collection populated before the find query happens.

Reason being, I need to apply the filtered params the user inputs against the population ref's from other collections.

**Problem**: 
I am trying to use the pre hook so I can populate the needed paths before the find query fires on the "SampleSchema". If I try to apply the filter to the SampleSchema without pre-populating the schema, the find can't correctly filter the results and it errors out.

```
ERROR: { CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Foo" at path "program" for model "Sample" ...}
```

So haven't been able to correctly get the pre find middleware hook working correctly.

```
SampleSchema.pre('find', function() {
  console.log('HELLO I FIRED FIND PRE HOOK');
  this.populate('program history type status')
}
```

How do I go about this?

Thank you

Comment: This question answers my question I had regarding this behavior.  I was wondering if my `pre(/find/)` hook was populating every document in the collection before applying the filters.  But since you're having the opposite problem I can deduce that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre find hook in mongoose. you only get `validate`, `save`, `remove`. You can read more on: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html